# expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘Desktop’

Tags: bash, scripts

Here is my bash script for converting the input temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter temperature in degrees Celsius: "
read celsius
temp=$(expr $celsius * 9 / 5 + 32 )
echo "Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: $temp"
```

I got this error message:

```
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘Desktop’
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ? Please can you [edit] and add some info

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed

Comment: The text of the bash script in the question was copied into my answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` symbol is a shell glob (filename generation) character it will expand to a list of the non-hidden files in the current directory - in your case, that appears to include a `Desktop` item.

To prevent that, you either need to turn off shell globbing, using `set -f` or `set -o noglob`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f
echo "Enter temperature in degrees Celsius: "
read celsius
temp=$(expr "$celsius" * 9 / 5 + 32 )
echo "Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: $temp"
```

or either quote or escape the `*` character to make it literal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter temperature in degrees Celsius: "
read celsius
temp=$(expr "$celsius" \* 9 / 5 + 32 )
echo "Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: $temp"
```

In either case you should get into the habit of double-quoting shell expansions like `$celsius`, to prevent shell expansion and word-splitting (especially when they contain arbitrary user input).

Answer (score 1):

Corrected bash script for converting the input temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit using the popular `bc` terminal program instead of `expr` in line 4:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter temperature in degrees Celsius: "
read celsius
temp=`echo "scale=1; $celsius*1.8 + 32" | bc` 
echo "Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: $temp"
```

`bc` for "basic calculator" is an arbitrary precision calculator language. bc is a lot more intuitive and easier to use than working clumsily and fumbling with an `expr` syntax error. The value of the `scale` function is the number of digits after the decimal point in the expression.